# Google draw image size downloaded is different from the page set up

Tags: google-drawings

My page setup is 1290 x 2796 pixels. But when I downloaded the image it is 1153 x 2500 pixels. Do Google Draw have limitations with the page setup? How can I fix this so the image downloaded will be the same as the page setup?

I did another page set up of 1080 x 1920 pixels and the image downloade was fine as the page setup.